# how to find free network id and chain id for private network for go ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, networkid

I want to deploy a test node for this I want to know which network id and chain id is free to use for this private network, is there a way to check which one is available to avoid any conflict with other developers/networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a private network, then the only rule is that netwotrkid must be an integer number. You choose it yourself. In order to interact with peers, in addition to the networkid match, the genesis file must match. Which is not possible with other private networks. And the list of addresses of public networks is here: https://chainlist.org/